# XML element and array

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am attempting to communicate with a piece of hardware which is sending the following two messages. At the time of receiving the messages, it is unknown which of the two message structures I have got.
Using XSD, I have taken the .xml and created the .xsd and C# files for each separately, but this is not practical in the final solution being I do not know the message which I will have. The developers have appeared to used the 'ParameterValue' in the first instance as an array and the second as a simple string. Is it possible to have a single piece of code which will 'Deserialize' both messages? If I use the code for the first message on the second, the ParameterValue field is an empty array.

==First message==

```
<Parameters>
  <Parameter>
    <ParameterName>ResponseCode</ParameterName>
    <ParameterValue>2</ParameterValue>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <ParameterName>ResponseValue</ParameterName>
    <ParameterValue>
      <ReturnParameters>
        <ReturnParameter>
          <ParameterName>Data1</ParameterName>
          <ParameterValue>Parameter Not Found</ParameterValue>
        </ReturnParameter>
        <ReturnParameter>
          <ParameterName>Data2</ParameterName>
          <ParameterValue>Parameter Not Found</ParameterValue>
        </ReturnParameter>
      </ReturnParameters>
    </ParameterValue>
  </Parameter>
</Parameters>
```

==Second message==

```
<Parameters>
  <Parameter>
    <ParameterName>ResponseCode</ParameterName>
    <ParameterValue>2</ParameterValue>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <ParameterName>ResponseValue</ParameterName>
    <ParameterValue>Success</ParameterValue>
  </Parameter>
</Parameters>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `mixed="true"` to your XSD.  This says that you want to combine XML elements with text. 
It will result in a `Text` field in your C# class.

http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_mixed.asp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="Parameters" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="Parameters" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:Locale="en-US">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Parameter">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ParameterName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="ParameterValue" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="ReturnParameters" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="ReturnParameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="ParameterName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                <xs:element name="ParameterValue" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

```
public partial class ParametersParameterParameterValue {

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(
        Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute(
        "ReturnParameter", 
        typeof(ParametersParameterParameterValueReturnParametersReturnParameter), 
        Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, 
        IsNullable=false)]

    public ParametersParameterParameterValueReturnParametersReturnParameter[][] 
        ReturnParameters { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string[] Text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can't believe it was that easy. Thanks for the quick reply.